# using Application.FileDialog to rename a file in VBA

Tags: vba, filedialog

Using VBA.  My script moves a file into a directory.  If that filename already exists in the target directory, I want the user to be prompted to rename the source file (the one that's being moved) before the move is executed.

Because I want the user to know what other files are in the directory already (so they don't choose the name of another file that's already there), my idea is to open a FileDialog box listing the contents of the directory, so that the user can use the FileDialog box's native renaming capability.  Then I'll loop that FileDialog until the source file and target file names are no longer the same.

Here's some sample code:

```
Sub testMoveFile()

Dim fso As FileSystemObject
Dim file1 As File
Dim file2 As File
Dim dialog As FileDialog

Set fso = New FileSystemObject
fso.CreateFolder "c:\dir1"
fso.CreateFolder "c:\dir2"
fso.CreateTextFile "c:\dir1\test.txt"
fso.CreateTextFile "c:\dir2\test.txt"
Set file1 = fso.GetFile("c:\dir1\test.txt")
Set file2 = fso.GetFile("c:\dir2\test.txt")

Set dialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)

While file1.Name = file2.Name
    dialog.InitialFileName = fso.GetParentFolderName(file2.Path)
    If dialog.Show = 0 Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
Wend

file1.Move "c:\dir2\" & file1.Name

End Sub
```

But when I rename file2 and click 'OK', I get an error:

```
Run-time error '53': File not found
```

and then going into the debugger shows that the value of file2.name is `<File not found>`.

I'm not sure what's happening here--is the object reference being lost once the file's renamed?  Is there an easier way to let the user rename from a dialog that shows all files in the target directory?  I'd also like to provide a default new name for the file, but I can't see how I'd do that using this method.

edit: at this point I'm looking into making a UserForm with a listbox that gets populated w/ the relevant filenames, and an input box with a default value for entering the new name.  Still not sure how to hold onto the object reference once the file gets renamed, though.

Comment: You're doing nothing to change `File2.Name` after displaying the dialog. It doesn't magically know what variable you're trying to change; you have to retrieve the value the user provided as the new file name and use it. You're displaying the dialog, discarding anything you might use from it, and trying to still do the original move operation using the original folder and file names.

Comment: @KenWhite, I thought that File2.Name was somehow dynamically linked to the name of the file in the system, and if the user renames the file by single-clicking on it in the dialog and retyping it, that the value of File2.name changes.  This is not the case?

Comment: No, it isn't. You've opened the file. The dialog displays the disk folder content, and lets your user pick a location, but it doesn't somehow read your mind or your code and know that you mean for that location to somehow affect `File2`. I think you're confused because you assign the `InitialFileName` to something related to `File2`, and you think that attaches the dialog to that file. It doesn't - it just reads the value currently in `File2.Path` and uses that name in an internal variable. You're still responsible for changing `File2` after the user tells you they've  chosen something.

Comment: ok, I've solved this by creating a UserForm for renaming the files, and making File1 and File2 available to the UserForm by making them public variables outside of procedures.  I'll post this as the solution when I'm allowed to answer the question.

Comment: Rather than creating your own `UserForm`, perhaps my answer will help you in using the original `FileDialog` and retrieve the user's selected name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a sample of using `Application.FileDialog` to return a filename that the user selected. Maybe it will help, as it demonstrates getting the value the user provided.

EDIT: Modified to be a "Save As" dialog instead of "File Open" dialog.

```
Sub TestFileDialog()
  Dim Dlg As FileDialog
  Set Dlg = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)

  Dlg.InitialFileName = "D:\Temp\Testing.txt"  ' Set suggested name for user
                                               ' This could be your "File2"

  If Dlg.Show = -1 Then
    Dim s As String
    s = Dlg.SelectedItems.Item(1)  ` Note that this is for single-selections!
  Else
    s = "No selection"
  End If
  MsgBox s
End Sub
```

Edit two: Based on comments, I cobbled together a sample that appears to do exactly what you want. You'll need to modify the variable assignments, of course, unless you're wanting to copy the same file from "D:\Temp" to "D:\Temp\Backup" over and over. :)

```
Sub TestFileMove()
  Dim fso As FileSystemObject

  Dim SourceFolder As String
  Dim DestFolder As String
  Dim SourceFile As String
  Dim DestFile As String

  Set fso = New FileSystemObject
  SourceFolder = "D:\Temp\"
  DestFolder = "D:\Temp\Backup\"
  SourceFile = "test.txt"
  Set InFile = fso.GetFile(SourceFolder & SourceFile)
  DestFile = DestFolder & SourceFile
  If fso.FileExists(DestFile) Then
    Dim Dlg As FileDialog
    Set Dlg = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)
    Dlg.InitialFileName = DestFile
    Do While True
      If Dlg.Show = 0 Then
        Exit Sub
      End If
      DestFile = Dlg.Item

      If Not fso.FileExists(DestFile) Then
        Exit Do
      End If
    Loop
  End If

  InFile.Move DestFile
End Sub
```

Comment: tested this--when I typed a filename that wasn't already in the directory (simulating a user typing a changed filename for a selected file), clicking "Open" did not return a value--it just kept me on the FileDialog until I exited by either selecting a file or clicking Cancel.

Comment: I used the `msoFileDialogOpen` from your original post. That makes this a file *open* dialog. The purpose was to show you how to retrieve the selection from the user after displaying the dialog. Change it to `msoFileDialogSaveAs` instead. (Sorry - I figured you'd modify it to suit your needs.) You can find the documentation for `msoFileDialogType` [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa208726(v=office.11).aspx). :)

Comment: I appreciate your patience and your willingness to assist me.  I understand how to retrieve the filename that a user has selected from a file dialog.  What I'm trying to do is incorporate renaming into that same dialog, so the user doesn't have to move through multiple dialogs to rename a file.  I've solved the problem with a userform by including a file list, an output box showing the original filename, and an input box for entering the new filename. but if you know a way for me to do it using FileDialog, that would be great.

Comment: Your original code would probably work, if you add a new variable to hold the user's selected name (for instance, `DestFile`, and change the last line to something like (untested) `File1.Move DestFile`. Your original code is confusing, though. You create a pair of text files (no content) in new folders, open those text files, and then try and copy the first one over the first one. Perhaps you should start a new question and ask how to do what you're really trying to do (or edit this one)? I think I've got it, but this one is getting cluttered with stuff that's making it hard to follow. :)

Comment: OK. One more edit. <g> The newly added code will do everything you want. It only presents the Save As dialog if the file already exists in the destination folder, and will not allow the user to overwrite the file that's already there. They have to enter a new file name or the operation cancels. This one is tested (somewhat) - I tested both without and with a file in the target folder of the same name, and with and without providing a new target filename. It's rough - I'm not a VB person. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's some really quick code that I knocked up but basically looks at it from a different angle. You could put a combobox on a userform and get it to list the items as the user types. Not pretty, but it's a start for you to make more robust. I have hardcoded the directory c:\ here, but this could come from a text box

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_KeyUp(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, 
       ByVal Shift As Integer)

Dim varListing() As Variant
Dim strFilename As String
Dim strFilePart As String
Dim intFiles As Integer

ComboBox1.MatchEntry = fmMatchEntryNone

strFilePart = ComboBox1.Value

strFilename = Dir("C:\" & strFilePart & "*.*", vbDirectory)

Do While strFilename <> ""
    intFiles = intFiles + 1
    ReDim Preserve varListing(1 To intFiles)
    varListing(intFiles) = strFilename
    strFilename = Dir()
Loop

On Error Resume Next
ComboBox1.List() = varListing
On Error GoTo 0

ComboBox1.DropDown

End Sub
```

Hope this helps. On error resume next is not the best thing to do but in this example stops it erroring if the variant has no files

Comment: This will give a directory listing in the combo box, but I don't understand how this helps to rename the file.