# Multiple dialog boxes in VB

Tags: vba

I'm having an issue that when I try to use multiple instances of file dialogs the information from the first is always overwritten by the selection in the second dialog.

What i need to do is:

1. Select a template file
2. Select a destination folder
3. Save the template file as a .docm file.

What happens is that the second time application.FileDialog is used all the information in fd is lost and is overwritten by the entries into fldr.

Can there only be one dialog object per macro?

```
Dim fd As FileDialog
Dim FileChosen As Integer
Dim FileName As String
Dim fldr As FileDialog
Dim fldrSelect As String


Dim i As Integer

Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

    'use the standard title and filters, but change the

    'initial folder

    fd.InitialFileName = "H:\UpdatedSalesTemplates\"
    fd.InitialView = msoFileDialogViewList

    'allow multiple file selection
    fd.AllowMultiSelect = True

FileChosen = fd.Show

    If FileChosen = -1 Then

'Select the directory using a file dialog
Set fldr = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

fldr.InitialView = msoFileDialogViewList
fldr.Title = "Select Destination"
fldr.AllowMultiSelect = False



fldrSelected = fldr.Show
```

'

Comment: Is this for VB or VBA?

Comment: You might check this post:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/8176278/122139

Answer (score 0):

[Microsoft says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff862446.aspx) that there may be only one: "...Each host application can only create a single instance of the FileDialog object...".

In any case, this shouldn't represent a serious problem as far as you can store all the relevant information (selected path, initial directory, etc.) in (string) variables.

Answer (score 0):

For such scenarios where you need a *file/folder* picker in one *macro/procedure/userform*, I use a custom made userform. See if you like it. Place commandbuttons and textboxes as shown below

**Screenshot**

[image]

**Code**

Note: Both the textboxes  `.Locked` property was set to `True` in design time so that the user cannot modify the textboxes manually.

```
Option Explicit

Dim Ret

'~~> Browse File
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Ret = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel Files (*.xlsx), *.xlsx")
    If Ret <> False Then TextBox1.Text = Ret
End Sub

'~~> Browse Folder
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Ret = BrowseForFolder("C:\")
    If Ret <> False Then TextBox2.Text = Ret
End Sub

Function BrowseForFolder(Optional OpenAt As Variant) As Variant
    Dim ShellApp As Object

    Set ShellApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application"). _
    BrowseForFolder(0, "Please choose a folder", 0, OpenAt)

    On Error Resume Next
    BrowseForFolder = ShellApp.self.Path
    On Error GoTo 0

    Set ShellApp = Nothing

    Select Case Mid(BrowseForFolder, 2, 1)
    Case Is = ":"
        If Left(BrowseForFolder, 1) = ":" Then GoTo Invalid
    Case Is = "\"
        If Not Left(BrowseForFolder, 1) = "\" Then GoTo Invalid
    Case Else
        GoTo Invalid
    End Select

    Exit Function
Invalid:
     '~~> If it was determined that the selection was invalid, set to False
    BrowseForFolder = False
End Function
```